# iOS8: IScreen.mainScreen().bounds unreliable to use for orientation change. Suggestions?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, device-orientation

if I use IScreen.mainScreen().bounds in order to get the size of the screen after orientation change, I sometimes get the "wrong" (="the other") screen size (associated with the orientation currently not to be displayed). I tried to update the values I get from IScreen.mainScreen().bounds directly in the func rotated() I added to my controller via the notification center:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "rotated", name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
[...]
rotated() {
    myBounds = IScreen.mainScreen().bounds
}
```

However, myBounds can yield the values associated with the orientation not currently active occasionally (especially when changing the orientation very fast on my latest generation iPad). Should I use another way of "getting" the screen size? Or should I read the values from IScreen.mainScreen().bounds elsewhere in my code?

Comment: I'm sure it's possible somehow as it seems to work correctly in the Spotify app :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the dimension returned from mainscreen().bound and then account for the orientation.  Use the method:

```
- (void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation 
                             duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

to capture the orientation change.  When you use the willRotateToInterfaceOrientation you should able to capture the orientation change that is happening even when you change the rotation quickly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately that method is listed as deprecated: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW171

Comment: and it doesn't rule out the problem either. It only returns the current values before the orientation change. This won't help as you get the same result when performing a 90° orientation change as for a 180° orientation change. But those cases are not the same, obviously :)

Comment: I also tried to use self.view.frame in the appropriate controller instead of IScreen.mainScreen().bounds but both seem to behave similar

Answer (score 0):

I seem to be able to handle the orientation change reliably by overriding viewDidLayoutSubviews() in the ViewController. I tried this and it seems to work correctly.